# Huge performance difference of the command find with and without using %M option to show permissions

Tags: linux, files, permissions, find, performance

On my CentOS 7.6, I have created a folder (called many_files) with 3,000,000 files, by running:

```
for i in {1..3000000}; do echo $i>$i; done;
```

I am using the command `find` to write the information about files in this directory into a file. This works surprisingly fast:

```
$ time find many_files -printf '%i %y %p\n'>info_file

real    0m6.970s
user    0m3.812s
sys     0m0.904s
```

Now if I add `%M` to get the permissions:

```
$ time find many_files -printf '%i %y %M %p\n'>info_file

real    2m30.677s
user    0m5.148s
sys     0m37.338s
```

The command takes much longer. This is very surprising to me, since in a C program we can use `struct stat` to get inode and permission information of a file and in the kernel the `struct inode` saves both these information.

**My Questions:**

1. What causes this behavior?
2. Is there a faster way to get file permissions for so many files?

Comment: The second question is the wrong question to ask. The real question is what you are doing with the output. If you are piping it somewhere for later processing of files based on the permissions, then you are probably doing it in a roundabout way. Instead you may want to use `-perm` with `find` to pick out the files with the permissions you're looking for.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Why is it wrong to ask that? If you're faced with an unexpected 20x slowdown, then surely you want to know if it can be avoided? `find -perm` will still need to look at the permissions, even if not output them, so would using it affect the slowdown in any way?

Comment: @ilkkachu You are correct. I assumed that the slowdown was due to the extra data produced, just like 0xSheepdog initially thought (which seems to not be the case). I would still not want to get the permissions as text like that if the intention is to process the files based on the permissions though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first version requires only to [`readdir(3)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/readdir.3)/[`getdents(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/getdents.2) the directory, when run on a filesystem supporting this feature (ext4: `filetype` feature displayed with `tune2fs -l /dev/xxx`, xfs: `ftype=1` displayed with `xfs_info /mount/point` ...).

The second version in addition *also* requires to [`stat(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/stat.2) each file, requiring an additional inode lookup, and thus more seeks on the filesystem and device, possibly quite slower if it's a rotating disk and cache wasn't kept. This `stat` is not required when looking only for name, inode and filetype because the directory entry is enough:

> ```
>   The linux_dirent structure is declared as follows:
>
>        struct linux_dirent {
>            unsigned long  d_ino;     /* Inode number */
>            unsigned long  d_off;     /* Offset to next linux_dirent */
>            unsigned short d_reclen;  /* Length of this linux_dirent */
>            char           d_name[];  /* Filename (null-terminated) */
>                              /* length is actually (d_reclen - 2 -
>                                 offsetof(struct linux_dirent, d_name)) */
>            /*
>            char           pad;       // Zero padding byte
>            char           d_type;    // File type (only since Linux
>                                      // 2.6.4); offset is (d_reclen - 1)
>            */
>        }
> ```

the same informations are available to `readdir(3)`:

> ```
> struct dirent {
>     ino_t          d_ino;       /* Inode number */
>     off_t          d_off;       /* Not an offset; see below */
>     unsigned short d_reclen;    /* Length of this record */
>     unsigned char  d_type;      /* Type of file; not supported
>                                    by all filesystem types */
>     char           d_name[256]; /* Null-terminated filename */
> };
> ```

Suspected but confirmed by comparing (on a smaller sample...) the two outputs of:

```
strace -o v1 find many_files -printf '%i %y %p\n'>info_file
strace -o v2 find many_files -printf '%i %y %M %p\n'>info_file
```

Which on my Linux amd64 kernel 5.0.x just shows as main difference:

[...]

```
 getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
 close(4)                                = 0
 fcntl(5, F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC, 0)            = 4
-write(1, "25499894 d many_files\n25502410 f"..., 4096) = 4096
-write(1, "iles/844\n25502253 f many_files/8"..., 4096) = 4096
-write(1, "096 f many_files/686\n25502095 f "..., 4096) = 4096
-write(1, "es/529\n25501938 f many_files/528"..., 4096) = 4096
-write(1, "1 f many_files/371\n25501780 f ma"..., 4096) = 4096
-write(1, "/214\n25497527 f many_files/213\n2"..., 4096) = 4096
-brk(0x55b29a933000)                     = 0x55b29a933000
+newfstatat(5, "1000", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
+newfstatat(5, "999", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
+newfstatat(5, "998", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
+newfstatat(5, "997", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
+newfstatat(5, "996", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
+newfstatat(5, "995", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
+newfstatat(5, "994", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
+newfstatat(5, "993", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
+newfstatat(5, "992", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
+newfstatat(5, "991", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
+newfstatat(5, "990", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
```

[...]

```
+newfstatat(5, "891", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
+write(1, "25499894 d drwxr-xr-x many_files"..., 4096) = 4096
+newfstatat(5, "890", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
```

[...]

Comment: Unfortunately, the `d_type` field of a dir entry is a non-standard feature, only present on Linux and BSD, as mentioned in the [readdir(3)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=readdir&sektion=3&manpath=SuSE+Linux/i386+11.3#end) manpage. (Though on Linux it is implemented on most filesystems that matter).

Comment: @mosvy That's ok, the question is tagged CentOS. But yes I understand that on other *nix, results may differ

Comment: Hum actually xfs (CentOS' default) support isn't quite clear...

Comment: added how to check if the filetype feature is present on xfs, in case xfs is in use.

Comment: I think it's supported on xfs -- when I was making a testcase for a glibc `glob(3)` that only triggered when the `d_type` field was absent, I had to use either minixfs or use the `GLOB_ALTDIRFUNC`.

Comment: Ah yes CentOS7' mkfs.xfs' man tells ftype=1 is the default.

Comment: It really is supported on centos 7 + xfs. Just tested it.